# Configure PL2303-based USB-to-RS232 adapter to stay awake when no active device is present

Tags: usb, serial-port, serial, home-automation-x10

I am resurrecting some X10 devices with the aid of a USB-to-RS232 adapter.  The problem is, that the adapter only works with the Firecracker device when there is another serial device on the line (the [Firecracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_Firecracker) is a pass-through device that monitors the RTS and DTR lines to do its magic).  Is the PL2303 going to sleep without a real device on the line?  Is there an option or command to keep it awake?  Is there a cable configuration that would make it work without a real serial device present?

Comment: [*Chip will NOT go to sleep mode when COM port is OPEN*](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_drivers/t1box01us17.txt) - so if a program keeps the port open (even if it doesn't write anything to the data lines) the chip won't go to sleep.

Comment: That seems to be a patch to a different driver than I am using ("Driver Change from v3.3.11.152").  What is that patch actually doing?

Comment: That's about the only thing I found when searching "PL2303" and "sleep". It looks like a driver for the PL2303, I assume it comes with some Lenovo computers since it's on their site.

Comment: I found a datasheet with a listing for a control register.  If someone knew how to set the control register, in particular to keep the PL2303 from going to sleep, that would work.  http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/116844/ETC1/PL2303/802/8/PL2303.html